# How to encrypt password while sending it to ldap server using spring ldap template

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory, spring-ldap

Iam using spring ldap template to connect to ldap server. Iam able to authenticate with ldap server using the following code

```
Filter filter = new EqualsFilter("sAMAccountName", <userID>);
boolean isValidUser = ldapTemplate.authenticate(<DN>, filter.encode(), <password>);
```

Everything is fine and working but ldap template is sending password as plain text on network . I want that to be encrypted on network. How can i do that with spring ldap template.

Comment: [click here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html) to know about ldap.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use SSL/TLS when passing data over the network. I don't think data is encrypted when you are using LDAP. Your LDAP server should be able to handle the password hashing when you get the credentials.

[SSL/TLS Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)

You have to issue a certificate for your domain and deploy a public key infrastructure to apply encryption.